# Indexing a list inside a list [:][0][0] notation?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

```
list1 = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19,20,21],[22,23,24]]]

for i in range(0,2):
     print(list1[:][i][1])
```

output =

```
[4, 5, 6]
[16, 17, 18]
```

how do I get the above code to work such that:

desired output =

```
2 14
5 17
```

What is the correct indexing notation for the list? I'm having particular trouble with the list[:] format as it seems to be ignored by the above code. Thx

Comment: `list1[start:end]` is slice notation, it makes a copy of the list starting at index `start` and ending at `end`. Both `start` and `end` are optional, and default to `0` and `len(list1)` respectively. This means that `list1[:]` is just a shallow copy of `list1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like?

```
>>> print(*map(' '.join, zip(*[map(str, list(zip(*x[:2]))[1]) for x in list1])), sep='\n')
2 14
5 17
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> print(*map(' '.join, zip(*[(str(x[0][1]), str(x[1][1])) for x in list1])), sep='\n')
2 14
5 17
>>>
```

To make it work on your code you would have to do:

```
for i in range(0,2):
     print(list1[0][i][1], list1[1][i][1])
```

Out:

```
2 14
5 17
```

The reason it your code didn't work is because it is getting the sublist from `i`, not the sublist's sublist.

Comment: This might be more helpful for OP if you add an explanation why this works.

Comment: Yea thanks for the solution! but i'm a bit of a python newb and don't really understand your above code. Is there not a different simple notation where you can just go list1[something][i][1] to get the code to work?

Comment: @clickclack Edited my answer, check the second part, remember what to do if it helps :), click the check mark

Comment: Thanks so much! Both solutions helped me (ps. I ticked but i don't think stack overflow registers cause I'm too new)